# Website still displays deleted files

Tags: web-hosting, webserver, cache, ftp

I went to update a website's CSS today and noticed whenever I uploaded the file with my changes nothing would happen - no changes would appear on my site. This was the same with any of the images I wanted to change. Experimenting, I changed the actual file name, uploaded it and changed the link to the external style sheet - it worked as expected. I then deleted the the CSS file completely...but still the website behaves as normal.

I've cleared my browser's cache of course and that made no difference.

Would anyone know what's going on? Is there something caching the entire site somewhere?

(I am using FileZilla. All other sites I have are behaving normally. There are no errors appearing in Filezilla's log when I upload or delete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it was actually CloudFlare that was caching my site. I cleared its cache and disabled it while I am developing

Comment: Cloudflare actually has a development mode that you can enable and it will disable caching for a certain amount of time.

Comment: Hmm... How about if you try from different network? Is it working?

Comment: @user555 cant until 2 days have passed